# Rails not recognizing nil objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm facing some weird errors on an application, all related to random crawlers requesting inexistent URLs and Rails failing to recognize that.

I.e. crawler requests [website]/local/favicon.ico and the code below fails to recognize that it should render a 404 since the object is nil, causing the app to break on the first method call:

```
@local = Local.find_by_slug(params[:c])
render_404(RuntimeError.new(request.path)) and return unless @local
```

I understand I could just block the crawlers IPs, but it doesn't look like the best solution.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this using Rails?

Comment: Wouldn't the assignment happen last?

Comment: @DaveNewton sorry, I didn't get it. Can you expand?

Comment: Until you edited it, the assignment to `@local` was happening after the `unless` call.

Answer (score 0):

Watch using periods in request strings and then looking for them in the params hash. Periods denote formats, so params[:c] in your example would likely only be favicon, and not the full path name.

I would suggest handling this in a rescue block as this particular method looks brittle.

Try something like:

```
begin
  @local = Local.find_by_slug(params[:c])
rescue Exception => e
  # Choose to do something with e here (email admin etc.)
  render_404(RuntimeError.new(request.path)) and return
end
```

Comment: That doesn't work because the first line never breaks - it doesn't find anything and creates a nil object that somehow passes the "unless @local" clause, proceeding to break in the first method called on it.